# How to set a specific size to the QPixmap and keep content in the same position and the same size?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I only want to resize the QPixmap, not the content.

Comment: What do you mean by original and target? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: Just draw the original pixmap onto the new pixmap using [`QPainter::drawPixmap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#drawPixmap-7)?

Comment: "How to resize QPixmap without content?" is a very confusing title. It suggests there is no content in the pixmap. Please rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QPixmap newPixmap(newWidth, newHeight);
newPixmap.fill(Qt::black); // or the color you like... maybe you want Qt::transparent?
QPainter painter(&newPixmap);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, oldPixmap);
```