# PyQt, Add blank space to Pixmap (copy one Pixmap into a blank Pixmat of higher resolution)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qpixmap

**Original image**

[image: input]

**New Image**

[image: ouput]

## Problem Statement

Suppose the original pixmap is of 300x300, and I want it to be extended in y axis by 200 pixels, new image being 300x500 pixels. How can I do it?

```py
# Current
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
self.setPixmap(pixmap)

# New
pixmap = self.pixmap().scaled(
            WIDTH,
            NEW_HEIGHT,
            Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
            Qt.SmoothTransformation)
self.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

## Things I tried:

1. Rescaling, but it only stretches the whole image to that resolution and distorts the image
2. I can create a new blank canvas of the new resolution, and ask the user to redraw or rewrite on the canvas again but it will be very inconvinient

**Application:**
I will be using this in my paint app, I am adding a scroll bar with my canvas, and with a button you can extend the canvas downwards and keep writing/drawing. The app is build on PyQt.

Comment: Use [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) - i.e. create a new pixmap of the required size and paint the old pixmap into it.

Comment: I already went through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73118892/how-to-set-a-specific-size-to-the-qpixmap-and-keep-content-in-the-same-position, but the problem being that I end up with a QPainter object, I need the end product as a pixmap

Comment: @ekhumoro Do you have any possible suggestions for the same?

Comment: My code base is complex as is I can't delete the last QPainter instance. and if I don't then this new instance of QPainter which draws oldPixmax on newPixmap won't work. Please suggest a word around.

Comment: You don't end up with a QPainter. The new pixmap has the old pixmap drawn onto it. It's literally four lines of simple code. It works perfectly fine for me. No work-around is needed.